# Android - Error at pinging a desktop

Tags: java, android, ip, ping

Well, in one of my tries to make some apps, I got this error:

Using this code:

```
String host = "192.168.0.137";
if (InetAddress.getByName(host).isReachable(4000)) {                            
    Log.i("Host",host + " is reachable");                            
}else{
    Log.i("Host",host + " is not reachable");                            
}
```

I try to ping my Desktop IP, 192.168.0.137, but I get an answer that it isn't reacheable. When I ping another Android smartphone, I get a "reachable" answer.

When I try this same code at a Java application, pinging my smartphone, it's reachable.

Yes, I'm using `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` and I'm running my app on phone, not on emulator. My device is connected at the same LAN of the desktop.

What's the problem?

Comment: From the emulator or from a device?  Are you using a virtual machine for your development environment?  Do you have a Wifi connection? etc etc.  Much more detail needed....

Comment: So AndroidDevice1 pinging Desktop fails, AndroidDevice1 pinging AndroidDevice2 works and Desktop (Java application) pinging AndroidDevice works too, right? So the problem is not related to Android but to your desktop not responding on network pings.

Comment: I said that I'm testing from a device with Wifi. And not using a virtual machine.

Comment: I'm doing some teste with other desktops and it's working. Problem is on my pc. Could it be firewall or something?

Comment: As already said, the PC might be a Problem. I had a Problem once, pinging my Desktop pc. The reason was that Win7 doesn't respond to pings, unless you configure it to do so.

Comment: I turned my firewall off and I reached my PC. So the problem is found. Now I have another problem. I need to find the pcs in my LAN, i was using ping for this, but, if some of then doesn't answer, what can I do?

Comment: When using the _ARP_ protocol, all devices in the subnet should answer. You can do this in a console with `arp -a` (in windows). [See here](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_Resolution_Protocol)